App bundle tampered after publishing to the google play store
I am currently using DexGuard's runtime checks (FileChecker) for file tampering detection in my application, The implementation works flawlessly when building an APK. However, when building an app bundle and publishing it to the Google Play Store, users complaint about being blocked by the DexGuard file tamper check. Does Google tamper the final apk?
This issue only happens with last version release two days ago.
Does anyone knows if google changed anything related recently?
Cheers!

I contacted Guardsquare support earlier and here is their reply,

We've recently seen this issue occur in bundle projects.
It seems the Google Play Store has stopped signing bundles with V1 signatures, which our file checker relies on.
We are already in contact with Google to discuss this change in
behavior, but unfortunately, there's no workaround for this issue yet.

Solution:

To stop the issue from occurring, you'll have to disable the file
checker.

